# Samsung seller store : release rejected CRITICAL: Install error/Unable to download app

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app, tizen-certificate

i have this message when i try to distribute my samsung tv app based on tizen web app in store , and i dont know how to resolve it , i already build my app with certficate based on my account but i got always this error, any idea plz

ERROR MESSAGE
[Doc Review Reject]
CRITICAL: Install error/Unable to download app. Package corrupted, please rebuild and resubmit your app. Make sure the author certificate (.p12) is the same one used when the app was registered. If you lost your certificate and password then unfortunately you will have to create a new app ID with the new certificate and make sure you back up your *.p12 file and password for future version-ups and sharing. With a new Author certificate you need to create a new application ID (or vice versa) in the store and begin the certification process again. Then you have to drop the old application ID.

I tried to rebuild my app but still always rejected

Comment: Has you tried to install that app version on your real device (TV) first?

Answer (score 2):

I solved by create another project and add a new samsung certificate and its done